# How can I determine which version of FFMPEG comes by default?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am honestly confused beyond belief about my package that I have installed for FFMPEG. It is, according to Synaptic, version:

```
4:0.8.1-1really0u1
```

For some reason, I feel like this is not the version that would come in the repositories and I feel like another PPA that I may have used installed a wrong version. I believe it was the VLC PPA for nightly builds.

Can anyone who does not have this PPA on their system tell me what version of FFMPEG they are running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yours is a PPA version, which is *most probably* similar to the official version. See below, from Precise (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
$ dpkg --list ffmpeg
ii  ffmpeg                                 4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1                        
Multimedia player, server, encoder and transcoder (transitional package)

$ apt-cache policy ffmpeg
ffmpeg:
  Installed: 4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1

$ ffmpeg

ffmpeg version 0.8.1-4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 22 2012 05:09:06 with gcc 4.6.3

.....
```

To reinstall the official version over the PPA version, you can either use the `ppa-purge` script (install that first!), or if you have already deleted the PPA, use

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg=4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1
```

You may have to throw a `--reinstall` switch in there if it fails.

Comment: My reason for wanting the package that you have is because the really0u1 version is terrible with dependencies of other programs. I checked Synaptic after I deleted the VLC PPA, and now it reads version "0ubuntu1", but using FFMPEG in command line reads "really0u1"....Any thoughts? This did answer my question, so I'll upvote and accept, but if you could help me with this by chance that would be awesome.

Comment: Just removing the PPA won't do it, you need to replace it with the "official" version. See edits towards bottom of answer

Comment: I gave what you had mentioned in the edit a try. It reinstalled (had to use `--reinstall`), but it still when I use it in Terminal reads `ffmpeg version 0.8.1-4:0.8.1-1really0u1`

Comment: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` give you the same version?

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian now use Libav, not FFmpeg. A slightly older ffmpeg binary is provided for "compatibility purposes" but is NOT in the ffmpeg-whatever package. It's contained in the `libav-tools` package. It;s now intended that for standalone use one uses `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`

Comment: @doug: good point, but it's irrelevant here -- `ffmpeg` in the official repos is a transitional/dummy package that points to `avconv`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` still reads `1really0u1`. Would purging and reinstalling `ffmpeg` work?

Comment: Yes, I'd try `--purge remove`, followed by  `--purge autoremove` and then `update` followed by `install`.

Comment: Just trying to point out that removing a transitional package won't remove the ffmpeg binary that was previously installed. I'd remove libav-tools if installed, then re-install. Or not use "ffmpeg" command at all

Comment: @doug : good catch!

Comment: I went ahead and purged ffmpeg AND removed libav-tools and reinstalled both. Thanks both to izx and doug. Now, it is working as it should.

Comment: as a note that it is "libav" not "ffmpeg" but a fork of it. FWIW.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to izx's solution of installing a specific version you can always revert a package to the distribution by tacking on the release at the end, like so:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg/precise
```

Comment: Never heard of that trick. It may not have worked for me specifically, but I'll have to keep that in mind for the future. Thanks Jorge!